# Call Auth:user() Laravel in extend Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I create my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResponsaveisController extends InternoController
{
}
```

I try to access Auth::user() multiple forms, all times return NULL

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

class InternoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(Auth::user());
    }
}
```

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you logged in to your app?

Answer (score 2):

This is taken directly from the Laravel docs

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet

You can read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) as it provides an alternative solution.